# Why is Perl running code that is not in a loop, during the loop?

Tags: perl

I'm developing in Perl for the first time, and I'm adding to a very large existing tool. So, I apologize for anything in advance.

The code below is a Perl test script:

```
SC "SA Text Here";
SC "SB Text Here";  # SA not important
SC "SB Text Here";

SC "SA Text Here";
SC "SB Text Here";
SC "SB Text Here";
```

The code:

```
my $skipA = -1;   
my $skipB = -1;    
my $skipC = -1;    
my $currentA = 0;
my $currentB = 0;
my $currentC = 0;

# Other subs set $skipA, $skipB, $skipC, but how they are set is not important. If set to anything other than -1, they should be a positive integer.

sub SC($)
{
  # Do some stuff and set $verb

  if( $verb eq "SA" )
  {
    # Starting
    $currentA++;
    $currentB = 0;
    $currentC = 0;

    # Check mode
    if( $sxMode eq "X" )
    {
      if( ( $skipA> -1 && $currentA > $skipA ) || $skipB > -1 )
      {
        logstatus 0, "DONE";
        $skipA= -1;
        $skipB = -1;
        $skipC = -1;
      }
    }
    $skipA = -1;
    $skipB = -1;
  }

  if( $verb eq "SB" )
  {
    # Starting
    $currentB++;
    $currentC = 0;

    # Check mode
    if( $sxMode eq "X" )
    {
      if( $skipB> -1 && $currentB > $skipB )
      {
        logstatus 0, "DONE";
        $skipA= -1;
        $skipB = -1;
        $skipC = -1;
      }
    }
    $skipC = -1;
  }
}

# Should execute the first loop, finish, then start the second loop
sub doOtherStuff()
{
  #Do other stuff here

  # This loop should take me to the $i-th SA in the test script
  for( my $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ )
  {
    $skipA = $currentA;
    print "THIS IS I $i\n";
    doSomething();  # Not important
  }

  # This loop should take me to the $j-th SB of the $i-th SA in the test script
  for( my $j = 1; $j <= 10; $j++ )
  {
    $skipB = $currentB;
    print "THIS IS J $j\n";
    doSomething();  # Not important
  }
```

EXAMPLE: If I start at 1.1 (currentA = 1, currentB = 1) and I want to skip to 2.3, I will get to 1.3. The expected output vs the actual output:

```
Actual Output               Expected Output
THIS IS I 1                 THIS IS I 1
THIS IS J 1                 THIS IS I 2
THIS IS J 2                 THIS IS J 1
THIS IS J 3                 THIS IS J 2
                            THIS IS J 3
```

When the Perl test script is run, it will see SC and execute that sub. With the help of some fancy buttons on a GUI, I can set $skipA and $skipB, and that will trigger **doOtherStuff()**.

If I comment out the 2nd loop in **doOtherStuff()**, then everything works fine (the 1st loop). But, if I add the 2nd loop, the 1st will not complete and the 2nd will take over. I've played around with it and I noticed that setting $skipB is causing the issue.

Even though I'm setting it after the 1st loop, it's still affecting it somehow ( this is the first and only time I'm setting $skipB ). So, I'm thinking the 1st loop should run until completion, and then move on to the 2nd.

Could this be a Perl issue or a tool issue? Could I be missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you're outputting a newline after $i? The output doesn't seem like you are. Also, doesn't `doSomething` mess with [select](http://p3rl.org/select)?

Comment: That is not all relevant code. Please make a  [mre].

Comment: If `doSomething` could be relevant, then show it, or better strip it down to just the part which causes the problem. Otherwise delete it.

Comment: @Yunnosch I updated the question. Please let me know if it's enough

Comment: There is nothing in your loops to make them exit prematurely, so you should get I 10 times and then J 10 times which doesn't remotely look like your expected output

Comment: @ChrisTurner You are right, it should be I 10 times then J 10 times. sorry, I hard coded the loop size for simplicity. But the idea is still the same.

Comment: What you posted doesn't compile

Comment: The shown code does not look like it should have any output. If you execute that code (with nothing else around it) you get the described output? That seems hard to believe.

Comment: Also even the last closing `}` seems to be missing. Please read [mre] again and try again to provide one.

Answer (score 3):

One way this can happen is if your loop is writing to a buffered `STDOUT` but your end-of-loop message goes to unbuffered `STDERR`.

```
(*STDOUT)->autoflush(0);   # use buffered STDOUT

for $i (1 .. 10) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        print STDERR "$i ";
    } else {
        print STDOUT "$i ";
    }
}
print STDERR "Done with the loop. ";
```

Output:

```
1 Done with the loop. 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Output buffering is a scheme used by Perl (and in many other places) for efficiency. There may be a delay between the time that output is added to the buffer and the buffer data is actually written to the output device.

See [`perldoc -v '$|'`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH) for information about how Perl uses output buffering and see the classic [Suffering From Buffering](https://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) article for even more information.

Comment: It looks like both are writing to STDOUT

Comment: This was an answer for the original question; it has nothing to do with the edited question.